# Improve auto-generated subtitles/CC for YouTube videos that are not mine

Tags: youtube, subtitles, translation

Is it possible to edit the auto-generated subtitles/closed captions for a YouTube video **from someone else**? How?

I found a Dutch video that I want to add English subtitles for, with these steps:

1. Fix the autogenerated Dutch captions
2. Use those for automatic translation to English
3. Fix the English translation

My guess is that this is the fastest way, and in the meantime I'll contribute to the Dutch subtitles as well.

But I'm stuck on the first step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a way to do so:

1. Use [Google2SRT](http://sourceforge.net/projects/google2srt/) to download the auto-generated captions to a `.srt` file ([Subrip text file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip#SubRip_text_file_format)):

[image: Google2SRT download dialog]

2. Use [Subtitle edit](http://www.nikse.dk/subtitleedit/) to edit the `.srt` file. This is an extremely powerful editor; it can even use Google Translate to start a file in a new language, that is then automatically opened side-by-side:

[image: using Subtitle Edit]

3. Go to the YouTube video in question, click on *More*, then *Transcript*, and open the drop down to choose *Add subtitles/CC*:

[image: "More" menu]

4. Choose the language that you want to upload the `.srt` file for, and under *Actions* choose *Upload a file*:

[image: "Actions" menu]

5. You can then upload your `.srt` file. Click *Submit for review* in the top right corner, answer *Yes, they are ready to be reviewed* and it will go into the review process that YouTube has.

*Note: as user130273 said in [another answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/96177/55949): not all videos allow this.*

Answer (score 2):

From the YouTube help page [Contribute subtitles & closed captions](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6054623):

> **Some channels** let you contribute subtitles and closed captions to their videos...

So, it's not available for all video.

There is an official YouTube [video example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9cKgwnFIAw) which explains the procedure.
It also has the feature enabled so you know how it works.

Comment: Clear video, but this is only about a fully on-line process with a lot of manual labor.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Extension that does all of this automatically , it has a built in machine translation option that it's superior to google auto generated translation [image]

Called [Dualsub](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dualsub/gnlibmlfpencglodjpgnalbdebfhpmfp/related?hl=en)

A list of extension that are really useful for such problems too
They are all on FF and google too

[substital](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/substital/) And [NekoCap](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nekocap/) is not that bad it allows you to edit the inserted sub title files from a video editor window while watching videos

Answer (score -1):

Just download the app [Save Subs](https://savesubs.com/)

Comment: This *only* lets you download the subtitles, and for the first video I tried it replicated every sentence 3 times! It also does not help if you address people as being stupid